# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult`1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4

I am trying to pass a stored procedure mapped to a method called `ListLeagueLeaders()` but the autogenerated method to invoke a stored procedure, `ObjectResult<ListLeagueLeaders_Result> ListLeagueLeaders()` is expecting an ObjectResult type. What can I do to fix this?

I thought of using LINQ instead of a stored procedure, but I want to give this tactic a last chance. Related: [LINQ to Entities instead of stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543261/linq-to-entities-instead-of-stored-procedure)

**HomeController**

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        HockeyStatsEntities db = new HockeyStatsEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "League leaders";
            {
                return View(db.ListLeagueLeaders());
            }
        }

        private ICollection<ListLeagueLeaders_Result> ListLeagueLeaders()
        {
            ICollection<ListLeagueLeaders_Result> leagueLeadersCollection = null;

            using (HockeyStatsEntities context = new HockeyStatsEntities())
            {
                foreach (ListLeagueLeaders_Result leagueLeader in
                          context.ListLeagueLeaders())
                {
                    leagueLeadersCollection.Add(leagueLeader);
                }
            }
            return leagueLeadersCollection;
        }
    }
```

**Model1.Context.cs**

```
public partial class HockeyStatsEntities : DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<Dim_Date> Dim_Date { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Dim_Player> Dim_Player { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Dim_Team> Dim_Team { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Fact_Statistics> Fact_Statistics { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Dim_Game> Dim_Game { get; set; }

        public virtual ObjectResult<ListLeagueLeaders_Result> ListLeagueLeaders()
        {
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(typeof(ListLeagueLeaders_Result).Assembly);

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<ListLeagueLeaders_Result>("ListLeagueLeaders");
        }
    }
```

**View:**

```
@model NHLStats2.Models.ListLeagueLeaders_Result

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error on your View. You need to reference the same object type which you are retuning from your controller action.

For example, if you are returning type of `List<Foo>` from your controller action, you can only make your view strongly typed to `List<Foo>` or `IList<Foo>` or `IEnumerable<Foo>` and etc.

Comment: I have edited my post. I have added the view, as you can see it is strongly type to `NHLStats2.Models.ListLeagueLeaders_Result`, shouldn't it be that way? Is that the root of the problem? If so, what would you replace this with?

Comment: replace `@model NHLStats2.Models.ListLeagueLeaders_Result` with `@model ObjectResult<NHLStats2.Models.ListLeagueLeaders_Result>`. It should work as far as I can tell by looking at your code.